# Сравнение файлов папке и в документе

Tags: c#, файлы

Есть такая проблема. Имеется файл .dat со списком файлов которые должны находится в папке. И сама папка с файлами. Как написать программу которая будет проверять если файл не записан в .dat документе и удалять его?

Comment: Загружаете весь dat в некий List<string>, далее получаете все файлы в папке и сверяете. Если в List такое название/путь отсутствует - файл под нож. Задача простейшая по сути и по этому возникает вопрос - в чем трудности и где ваши попытки?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Трудность заключается конкретно в методе сверки файлов с .dat документом. Получение списка файлов и текста в .dat документе в стринг происходит успешно. Был бы крайне признателен за пример в виде куска кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну предположим у нас есть некий `files.dat`, внутри которого всего две строки:

```
File.txt
Image.png
```

- Первым делом нам надо его считать:

  ```
  var list = File.ReadAllLines("files.dat");
  ```

Это выдаст нам массив строк (`string[]`), где каждый объект будет = 1 строке из файла.

- Теперь удаляем из директории все, что не содержится в этом массиве:

  ```
  foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("Dir"))
  {
      var info = new FileInfo(file);
      if (!list.Contains(info.Name))
          File.Delete(file);
  }
  ```

`FileInfo` здесь для того, что бы отделить путь и получить чисто название с расширением, способов это сделать уйма, я просто ленив.. Но вообще по хорошему лучше сверять не просто файл, а полный путь!

---

Я создал тестовые файлы для примера, до запуска в папке находится следующее:

[image: Files]

После запуска имеем следующее:

[image: Result]

Как видим, все лишнее успешно удалилось.

Comment: Спасибо, а если в строке храниться еще что-то кроме названия файла, к примеру MD5 хэш? То как быть?

Comment: @HoneyCake Все зависит от формата. Самое банальное - некий символ, который разделит это все (прим.: `File.txt|03a28ae7e8a544566cfbe0ba3b75c60b|1234574` (имя|md5|размер) ), тогда просто дописываете разбитие каждой строки по символу с помощью `Split()`. Я бы на вашем месте выбрал что более удобное (JSON например), для удобства можете создать себе класс, который будет содержать все эти данные. Ну и перед удалением по аналогии с `if (!list.Contains(info.Name))` проверяете на соответствие.